# How can I calculate the amount of HF in aquoues solution of NH4F and an aquoues solution of NH4HF2?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, solutions

Dissociation of $\ce{NH4F}$ and $\ce{NH4HF2}$ in water is complete, I assume:
$$\ce{NH4F -> NH4+ + F-}$$
and
$$\ce{NH4HF2 -> NH4+ + HF2-}$$

Can I calculate the amount of $\ce{HF}$ in these solutions from this equilibrium?

$$\ce{HF + F- <=> HF2-}$$

$$\mathrm{K_2}=\dfrac{\ce{[HF^{2-}]}}{\ce{[HF][F^-]}}=4,7$$

If I know the concentrations of NH4F in water and NH4HF2 in water.

Comment: Is this a homework or book question? If so we'll need to see the exact question to help. Also we have a "homework" policy that requires you to show some work. // If this is some sort of other inquiry, please explain the context better so we can figure out how to help.

Comment: It's not homework. It's for my work. A reviewer asked me to calculate this for a paper I want to publish. But I'm so lost, I haven't done these calculations since the first year of Uni. Like I have some ideas on how to calculate this, but I'm not entirely sure. I prepared the solutions of NH4F and NH4HF2 in water and I need to calculate the amount of HF in these solutions. The concentrations of NH4F is 5 M and NH4HF2 is 0,18 M.

Comment: Ok, for a paper. In that case you'll want "reasonable" calculations not just some tripe 'theoretical" calculations. In other words, your solutions are so concentrated that you'll need *activities,* not the raw concentrations to do the calculations. Not sure where you'd find that data.

Comment: I think theoretical are enough, the reviewer asked to estimate the amount of HF.

Comment: $$\mathrm{K_2}=\dfrac{\ce{[HF2^-]}}{\ce{[HF][F^-]}}=4.7$$

Answer (score 2):

**WRONG SOLUTION: OP clarified that there are two separate solutions, not a mixture of the salts.**

Assuming:

(1) that concentrations can be used instead of activities (bad assumption...)
(2) The concentration of the ions $\ce{H2F-}$ and $\ce{F-}$ is so large that the final concentrations will be the same as the initial concentrations.
(3) Since HF is a relatively weak acid, little $\ce{HF}$ will dissociate into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{F-}$.

Using equilibrium:
$$\mathrm{K_2}=\dfrac{\ce{[HF^{2-}]}}{\ce{[HF][F^-]}}=4.7$$

From 5 molar $\ce{NH4F}$, $\ce{[F-] = \pu{5 molar}}$

From 0.18 molar $\ce{NH4HF2}$, $\ce{HF_2^- = \pu{0.18 molar}}$

So plugging the number in:

$$\mathrm{K_2}=\dfrac{\ce{[HF^{2-}]}}{\ce{[HF][F^-]}} = \dfrac{0.18}{\ce{[HF]}\times 5}=4.7$$

$$\ce{[HF] = 0.008 molar}$$

For the final concentrations $\ce{[HF] \ll [H2F-]}$, so the assumption that the dissociation of $\ce{H2F-}$ can be ignored is valid. The $\ce{HF}$ will dissociate and acidify the solution, but still $\ce{[HF] + [H+] \ll [H2F-]}$

Comment: The NH4F and NH4HF2 are two separate solutions, c(NH4F)=5M, and c(NH4HF2)=0.18 M. For each of these solutions, that are not mixed I need to determine the concentration of HF. In the expression K2 for NH4F solution I only know the concentration of F- which is 5, but for conc. of HF2- and HF are unknown. This is where I get lost, because I don't know if I can assume this concentrations are maybe the same, or one is the same as F-

Answer (score 0):

Let us calculate first the $\ce{NH4F}$ problem. The ion $\ce{F-}$ reacts partially with water according to

$$\ce{F- + H_2O <=> HF + OH-}$$

The equilibrium constant $K_\mathrm{b}$ of this equilibrium is defined by

$$K_\mathrm{b} = \frac{[\ce{HF}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{F-}]}$$

The numerical value of $K_\mathrm{b}$ is needed, but it is not tabulated. However it can be obtained from the dissociation constant $K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{HF}$ in water, which can be found in the tables : $K_\mathrm{a} = 10^{-3.17}$. So $K_\mathrm{b} = K_\mathrm{w}/K_\mathrm{a} =  10^{-14}/ 10^{-3.17} = 10^{-10.83}$. This numerical value is now introduced in the definition of $K_\mathrm{b}$

We can simplify by writing :  $[\ce{HF}]=[\ce{OH-}]= x$. If we admit that $x$ is small, $[\ce{F-}]$ =  $\pu{5 M}$. Solving this equation gives : $x^2 = 5·10^{-{10.83}}$ and $x = 3.84 \cdot 10^{-6}$. This is the expected result  : In $\ce{KF}$ $\pu{3 M}$, the concentration of $\ce{HF}$ is $\pu{3.84 \times 10^{-6} M}$.

Let's now calculate the problem of $\ce{NH4HF2}$ in a solution $\pu{0.18 M}$, where the following equilibrium is given :

$$\ce{F- + HF <=> HF2-}$$

In this solution, there was $\pu{0.18 M}$ $\ce{HF2-}$ in the beginning, from which $x$ is transformed into $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{F-}$. So the final concentration of $\ce{HF2-}$ is $0.18 - x$. The equilibrium constant $K_2$ of this equilibrium is

$$K_2 = \frac{[\ce{HF2-}]}{[\ce{HF}][\ce{F-}]} = \frac{0.18-x}{x^2} = 4.7$$

This is an equation to solve, and the solution is $x = 0.116$. So the concentration of $\ce{HF}$ in $\pu{0.18 M}$ $\ce{NH4HF2-}$ is $[\ce{HF}] = \pu{0.116 M}$

Comment: Don't think that you can neglect $\ce{NH4+}$ as a weak acid.